# IP-адрес устройства

Tags: android, ip-address

Реализую что-то вроде Сокет-соединения между двумя телефонами(один сервер, другой клиент). Для подключения клиенту нужен IP-адрес сервера. Вопрос: Как правильно определить сетевой  IP-адрес телефона?

Comment: Какого телефона? Сотового?

Comment: Да, на андроиде

Answer (score 1):

При работе телефона через провайдерский интернет 2/3/4G, телефон получает серый ip из внутренней провайдерской сети. С вайфаем, чаще всего, аналогично. Без дополнительного контракта с провайдером, доступ к этому телефону из интернета невозможен.

Все сервисы IP-телефонии используют промежуточный сервер сигнализации для того, чтобы клиенты могли друг друга найти.

Comment: Тогда как можно реализовать на андроиде сервер и подключиться к нему с другого андроид телефона

Comment: @user186301, нельзя. Даже в пределах одного провайдера телефоны друг друга через провайдерскую сеть скорее всего видеть не будут.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае, нужен белый IP-Address и статичный адрес в подсети роутера. 
Так же необходимо сделать NAT-запись на роутере, с нужным портом.
и ip будет иметь формат: `address:port`

Про мобильный интернет добавить нечего. Кстати, не все телефонные операторы предоставляют белый IP.